# How do i end an ongoing mouseevent in fabricjs

Tags: mouseevent, fabricjs

i am trying to achieve a collision detection with fabricjs. 
In the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwQbRQ) i'm providing, the blue ball should not be able to cross the red line. The collision detection works fine, but i cant figure out how to end the dragging once the collision takes place.

I tryed to change the balls options (i commented it out in the example) but all changes, including:

```
canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch();
```

are for the next mouse event, but doesnt affect the currently running one.
How do i end the currently ongoing mouse event?

example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwQbRQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i could solve it with

```
lockMovement
```

[updated link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaQORX?editors=001)